# Different color scheme in one type of file

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

In sublime text 3 i have some trouble with color scheme: in different files with one type of file different color scheme. This problem i will see with JS, CSS syntax. Example:

Screen with color scheme what i set - file1.js (Oceanic Next Color), here is good:
[image]

And in other file - file2.js (at the same folder):
[image]

My user config:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Oceanic Next Color Scheme/Oceanic Next.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "theme": "Broceanic.sublime-theme"
}
```

Packages list:
Babel, Handlebars, Oceanic Next Color, Theme Broceanic;

Sublime version: 3103

OS: Window 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: deleting project workplace file.